# Where can I find a good blog on Averroes

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy

I enjoy learning about the philosophy of Averroes. Averroes was a contemporary of Maimonides (Jewish philosopher), Musa ibn Maymun in Arabic. Both were rationalists and great thinkers. Both lived in Spain. I know much about Maimonides but I am ignorant about Averroes, other than he was a great rationalist. Where can I find a good, helpful English blog which deals with the topic of Averroes and his views?
Many thanks.

Comment: I'd say that this question is rather a bad fit on this site. Maybe the history of science SE or a philosophy site if available could be a better match. In Arabic I would know a website of a researcher who mainly analysed ibn Rushds work and could be regarded as a specialist.

Comment: https://medievalphilosophywithrhodi.wordpress.com/ may be a site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this website (http://www.muslimphilosophy.com/ir/index.html) you can find all his books in English and Arabic. Books and articles and even movies. It is everything Ibn Rush related.

Generally speaking this website muslimphilosophy.com is a very good site for Islamic philosophy in general where you find other philosophers of the Islamic tradition like Sina, Ghazali and Ibn Taymiyah. And since you enjoy Maimonides you would probably enjoy this too: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/maimonides-islamic/

May Allah increase both of our intellects and guide us on the right path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for sharing the links about Averroes. I will look at the essays. Thaks again!